# Can ANTLR grammar delegate some of its parsing to an opaque parser

Tags: antlr, antlr4

Suppose we have a non-ANTLR parser that can parse certain expressions. The parser is represented by a C++ function that accepts a string and returns a parsed object. We can additionally assume that we have a way to tell how much of the string was consumed in the process. (In practice, our parser is Bison-based.)

Does ANTLR support using this as a building block in a grammar? One should assume that the two shared some tokens, such as parentheses.

To exemplify, suppose "expr" below is to be parsed by the non-ANTLR parser, and the rest of it is to be described using an ANTLR grammar:

`if expr then do_something`

Is there such a mechanism?

Comment: The main problem is with the lexer. Antlr lexers are not parser aware. You will need to either use lexer modes or write a proper unbuffered token stream.

Comment: For example you can do this with a lexer mode if you can assume that an "if" starts an expression. In the action of the "if", push a new mode. In an "Expr" lexer rule for that mode, the action should start your embedded parser then pop mode when done. You will need to set up the token stream for the next token following the expression. This parser embeds a C# parser within an Antlr4 grammar, showing how to do that. https://github.com/kaby76/AntlrExamples/tree/master/AntlrTargetCSharp .

Comment: Looks like a bona fide "island grammar", but in your example, the embedded grammar seems to be an ANTLR grammar. In my case, the embedded grammar is not written in ANTLR. To ANTLR, there's only a consumer of the raw stream, I need ANTLR to give control to it at specific points in the parse, and then skip over whatever has been consumed, resuming its tokenizing and parsing.

Comment: It doesn't have to be an embedded Antlr parser. Just call your parser with the rest of the input from the current char position in the buffer. Your parser will need to return the point in the input where to restart the parser following the expression by calling Seek(). In addition, you will need to return some kind of token corresponding to the entire expression. Antlr lexers do not "coordinate" with the Antlr parser.